# How can I retrieve an image path from another page using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, image, path

This is my case: I have a page with a banner that will be frequently updated, this means the image path of the banner will be different each time the page is updated (can't be overwritten). Anyway, it will be inside a div or container with a constant name.

What I need to do is retrieve that image path and print it in a different page, so if the banner changes in the first page, it will automatically change in the second one.

I thought maybe some javascript could do the work, but I am not really sure how to get the image path from inside the div.

Any help will be appreciated, greetings from Argentina

Comment: Can you use jQuery? if yes you may get the first <img> tag inside the div frame (you know its ID) and read the src attribute value.

Comment: Could you post some sample HTML to help people provide relative answers?

Comment: Yes, it's really simple actually, I just need to retrieve the image from a div like this one:  (i'm not sure how to add the code formatting)
<div id="pubHero">
    <div style="height: 180px; width: 940px;">
   <img id="cidHero" class="cidHeroHide" src="example-image.jpg" alt="" usemap="#promoMap" width="960" height="180" border="0" />
    </div>
</div>

Comment: And yes, i could use jQuery as well :)

Answer (score 0):

solution using html5 and javascript is this

```
  you can get the image tag through javascript(as u say it is in div
  and whose id you know)  
  something like
  src = document.getElementById("id").childnodes[0].src
  should work for u

  then you can store this src in the localStorage

  localStorage["src"] = src;

  as soon as you store something in localstorage it will fire a 
  "storage" event in all the other pages except the page in which 
  you have actually stored the src


 so handle "storage" event in the other pages like this

     window.addEventListener("storage",func,false);

     function func(event)
     {

         src  = localStorage[event.key];
        //now src has the updated src :)
     }
```